# Facebook FQL Query to extract full thread from each user in the OTHER mailbox

Tags: facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

New to FQL and wanted to extract "OTHER" mailbox archived or not and group all body messages by user.  The query example below grabs each message and in INBOX only. `folder_id` is `0` for inbox, `1` for outbox and `4` for updates.  What is the option for the OTHER inbox?

```
SELECT message_id, thread_id, author_id, body, created_time, attachment FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OR operator

> SELECT message_id, thread_id, author_id, body, created_time, attachment FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0 OR folder_id = 1 OR folder_id = 4)